# Magento checkout steps move review before payment in Magento checkout

Tags: php, magento

I'd like to change the order of the One page checkout in Magento. I want to move the Review step before the Payment.

I've already changed the OnepageController to

```
 $stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review', 'payment');
```

and saveShippingMethodAction in OnepageController to

```
            $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
            $result['update_section'] = array(

                'name' => 'review',

                'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()

            );
```

However i'm getting error `Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\cfh\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php on line 289`

when I save the shipping method.

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/how-can-i-remove-the-review-step-in-onepage-checkout
have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');` before `$result['update_section']`